# USB Backwards-Compatibility

Tags: usb

Is the USB 3.0 (and latest 3.2) specification only guaranteed to be
backwards compatible to USB 2.0?

Some Arduino microcontrollers follow the original low-speed 1.5 Mb/s
USB standard, so equivalently, are new smartphones and laptops not
guaranteed to work with them?  A specific example product which
does not support low-speed USB would help.

Comment: just upgrade the Arduino to get USB2 like Arduino Mini 05 which is getting old

Comment: At least for boards legitimately wearing the trademark, "upgrading" the Arduino is unlikely to change compatibility in a more than random way - in theory, any should work, if they don't it has more to do with *implementation quirks* of each end than specification differences.  That said, USB connection of an Arduino to a phone playing host, while demonstrated, is often a bit iffy.  And hosting a phone from an embedded gadget can tend to mean implementing some fairly heavy software protocols including crypto - unclear if the IOIO idea was updated for secured ADB or if ADK still works.

Comment: From a practical standpoint: keyboards and mice are almost always implemented as USB 1.1 devices. Dropping support for these devices under USB 3.x would be a non-starter.

Comment: @duskwuff But a smartphone maker might not care since keyboards and mice are not common in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latest USB (3.0-3.1-3.2) specifications guarantee to include USB 2.0 as a "side-band" channel, so USB 2.0 runs on independent set of wires (legacy D+ and D-). This is the requirement of the standard. The USB 2.0, in turn, guarantees backward compatibility with FS (12 Mbps signal rate) and LS (1.5 Mbps rate) devices.

Low-speed and FS USB devices aren't going to disappear soon, because the cost (and energy consumption) of Super-Speed protocol controllers is prohibitive, and require thick ugly stiff cables which are not ergonomic.

All new laptops/PCs/smartphones use processors and chipsets with USB based on Intel's xHCI controller specifications, with IP provided [mostly by Synopsys](https://www.synopsys.com/designware-ip/interface-ip/usb.html), and modern xHCI IP includes all USB 2.0 functionality, and therefore supports all legacy modes.

**ADDENDUM:** USB 3.2 specifications, in Section 3 "Architectural Overview", explicitly states:

> USB 3.2 is a dual-bus architecture that provides backward
>   compatibility with USB 2.0. One bus is a USB 2.0 bus (see Universal
>   Serial Bus Specification, Revision 2.0) and the other is an Enhanced
>   SuperSpeed bus (see Section 3.1). USB 3.2 specifically adds dual-lane
>   support.

As one can see, it explicitly includes the USB 2.0 Specifications. They, in turn, read in Section 4.2.2

> There are three data rates:
>
> • The USB high-speed signaling bit rate is 480 Mb/s.
>
> • The USB full-speed signaling bit rate is 12 Mb/s.
>
> • A limited capability low-speed signaling mode is also defined at 1.5 Mb/s.
>
> USB 2.0 host controllers and hubs provide capabilities so that
>   full-speed and low-speed data can be transmitted at high-speed between
>   the host controller and the hub, but transmitted between the hub and
>   the device at full-speed or low-speed. This capability minimizes the
>   impact that full-speed and low-speed devices have upon the bandwidth
>   available for high-speed devices.

Comment: OK, I didn't realize that these compatibilities could be chained like that.  Is that spelled out clearly in a document or FAQ or something released by the USB Implementers Forum?  Maybe you could add a reference/quote to help me be certain that this is not open to interpretation?

Comment: @bobuhito, https://usb.org/documents

Comment: You can't be more specific?  I honestly looked there before I posted the question.

Comment: Thanks for the edits!  By the way, I looked at my Windows Device Manager and found
two USB host controllers: An "Enhanced PCI to USB" interface and the xHCI you mentioned.
On that "Enhanced" interface is a "Root Hub", on which is a "Generic USB Hub" with TT
(just like 90% of all laptops I presume).  I'm guessing that this TT does all of this
low-speed work, so it seems my xHCI controller never gets involved (even though your
answer tells me the xHCI controller could have handled the low-speed messages also -
If I'm making some mistake, please let me know).

Comment: To be specific, it looks like the two controllers are built by the same vendor (Shinko Shoji), so they're probably on the same chip.  The Generic USB Hub, however, shows AMD as the vendor, so I assume its chip is different and that the low-speed capability is redundantly present on both chips.

Comment: @bobuhito, during transitional period the USB3-USB2 duality was managed by simple pair of old EHCI and new xHCI controllers. Since about 2013 the newer generation of xHCI controllers can handle all modes by itself at "root port". Still the  USB3 maintain "dual bus" arcitecture, and in the case of hubs attached to the root port, both SS channel and USB2 channel are active simultaneously. The support for LS/FS from root hub comes naturally from xHCI, and if hubs are attached, the support comes over so-called "split transactions" and "transaction translators" built in hubs.